# Sending Arduno Yun pin information via serial1 to linino python script, over UDP to Max

Tags: python, linux, tcp, udp, arduino

Now trying to get my arduino sketch to be sent through the python script. I can't get it to send over.

Arduino code.

```
    /* Sketch for reading 4 analogue inputs for glove
*/

// Setup pin locations
int flexPin0 = A0; //analog pin 0
int flexPin1 = A1; //analog pin 1
int flexPin2 = A2; //analog pin 2
int flexPin3 = A3; //analog pin 3

int inByte = 0;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }  
  establishContact(); 
}

void loop(){
  // Read values
    // if we get a valid byte, read analog ins:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // get incoming byte:
    inByte = Serial.read();

  int flexSensorReading0 = analogRead(flexPin0); 
  delay(10);
  int flexSensorReading1 = analogRead(flexPin1);
  delay(10);
  int flexSensorReading2 = analogRead(flexPin2); 
  delay(10);
  int flexSensorReading3 = analogRead(flexPin3); 
  delay(10);

  // Output results to serial
    Serial.write(flexSensorReading0);
    Serial.write(flexSensorReading1);
    Serial.write(flexSensorReading2);
    Serial.write(flexSensorReading3);

  delay(50); //just here to slow down the output for easier reading
  }
}

void establishContact() {
  while (Serial.available() <= 0) {
    Serial.println('A');   // send a capital A
    delay(500);
  }
}
```

Python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyATH0', 9600)


while ser.read() != 'A':
#   do nothing
    pass


UDP_IP = "192.168.1.242"   #Max IP address
UDP_PORT = 8888
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP

while True: # ser.readline() == 'A':
    data_raw = read(8) #read 8 bytes
    sock.sendto(bytes(data_raw), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT)) #sends the byte
    ser.write('A')

#recvmsg=sock.recv(1024) #read response
#print recvmsg
sock.close()
```

Now getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/sda1/udpgit.py", line 8, in <module>
    while ser.read() != 'A':
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyserial-2.7-py2.7.egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 475, in read
    raise SerialException('device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)')
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
```

The python sketch runs when a blank sketch is on the arduino side, but as soon as I try and use serial1 it gives that error.

I'm using an Arduino Yun to try and communicate over wifi into Max!
Thanks!

Comment: your phyton script will stay forever in thr while 1 loop, what do you expect?

Comment: I see! That would make sense, I've only been using python for about 3 days, and I'm afraid I don't know any better. Would you be able to help me fix it? Thanks

Comment: what do you want to do? wait for an "A" and then send the raw value to UDP?

Comment: Yes. But the A isn;t even that important, just the raw data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fir of all you need to get over that infinite loop. You just want to wait until you get an 'A' so change the condition from "always true" (1) to "until we read an 'A'"

```
while ser.readline() != 'A':
    //do nothing
```

then open the socket

```
UDP_IP = "192.168.1.242"   #Uno IP address
UDP_PORT = 8888
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
```

now we need to read an arduino reading, with is composed of 8 byte (every reading is an int, so 2 byte), also you are NOT writing the "end of line" character (\n) so readLine() won't work;

```
data_raw = read(8) #read 8 byte
sock.sendto(bytes(MESSAGE), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT)) #send byte
recvmsg=sock.recv(1024) #read response messagge (are you sure aout this?)
print recvmsg
```

now we can close the socket. or loop for next 8byte, if we are looking for another reading just loop the above code.

```
sock.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!

I assume the do nothing is supposed to be a # comment?
And it's supposed to be indented until print recvmsg (which I've commented out for the moment)
Now I'm getting a lovely error (yay), asking if the device is disconnected or multiple access on port... Any ideas?
Again, thanks
Also I tried resetting the arduino side to stop it using the serial port..

Comment: yes it is a comment (//is c and many other langauages comment) and NO, it is not idented. I want the pythod do nothing util it read a strin that is just 'A'. if, for example, it read 'AA' or 'jsdlkajdlsajdklas' it wuold enter the while (witch in empty) so go back to the condition. you can write it like this:

line = serial.readLine()
while (line != 'A'):{
    line = serial.readLine()
}

Comment: Ah, I understand now. But If I remove the indentation, then I get an error requiring indentation on line
UDP_IP = "192.168.1.242"

Comment: i put in a pass function after it which solved that bit, but i'm getting nothing through still. But still, no errors!

Comment: where do you see nothing? As far as i know there is nothing to read the udp, so you can use a print() or similar to know when you are sending the datagram, and you can sniff the network with wireshark

Comment: Max Msp is set up on that addresss and port, and I've got another laptop sending to it to make sure it's working.I think I may know the issue though, to keep reading results, the arduino script needs to be sent to it. In the test max patch for the arduino sketch, this is done by banging a "65" message into the serial port. Is there a way I can mimic this in python when it's connected? Thanks

Comment: arduino send a reafing for every char readed, so a ser.write('a'); after every reading in python should be enougth

Comment: I've put it after the sock.sendto but now i get the device disconnected or multiple access on port? error from before..

Comment: I've posted it in as an answer :)

Comment: you have to put in a loop data_raw = read(8) #read 8 bytes

sock.sendto(bytes(data_raw), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT)) #sends the byte

ser.write('A')

Comment: Do I need a while or anything? Like while 1 ? or while ser.readline() == 'A': ?

Answer (score 0):

Error!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/sda1/udpgit.py", line 8, in <module>
    while ser.read() != 'A':
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyserial-2.7-py2.7.egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 475, in read
    raise SerialException('device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)')
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
```

Comment: that code does only ONE reading. you have to add a loop if you want to read more value! the read, the sendto and the write should loop until you need values.

Comment: while ser.readline() == 'A':
        data_raw = read(8) #read 8 bytes
        sock.sendto(bytes(data_raw), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT)) #sends the byte
        ser.write('A')

Comment: you have to while until you need it, so if you want the program to read forever use a while 1.
with a while ser.readline() == 'A' you will read only ultil serial buffer is filled with A, then your program will exit. But because arduino write only one A, witch is consumed to exit the first python while, so you will never enter that while

Comment: Thanks, using while ser.readline() == 'A': works lovely until I upload the arduino sketch, then it freaks out at   File "/mnt/sda1/udpgit.py", line 7, in <module>
    while ser.readline() != 'A':

So close

Comment: serial communication can be used only by one device at time, and serial port is used to send the program to the arduino. That's why SerialMonitor autoclose itself when you upload code to the arduino.

Comment: The serial used for uploading the sketch (serial) is a different one to the python serial used (serial1).

Comment: you are right, then probably is the arduino reboot that create some problem, maybe it break the protocol as when rebooting the pin may alter their staus, or maybe there are byte half written.. Is is strange that python broke, but you can catch that exception

Comment: Yeah, so would an option be to add an except pass before the whileser.realine() != 'A': ?

Comment: Or is there an easier way just to reset it through python?

Comment: forget about reset, upload, and trick like watchdog, a good code should not relay on this (this does not mean you shouldn't use them, but they should be the exception of the exception).
i would simply put the code of the loop inside a try exept. That's how you should handle exception (aka error)

Comment: oh and as there is 4 numbers, each reading to 1024, that means I need to read 12 bytes yeah?

Comment: no, you have 4 numbers, of 2 byte each (int), that means 8 byte.
If you use print() instead of write on the arduino code, then you won't print raw byte but its char rapresentation, where every dgit is a byte. but then the size would be dinamic and equal or bigger (For example if you use - between number, you may have: "1-500-514-1023-", 15 byte, as you may immagine this is bad because use a lot more bandwidth and is harder to parse, BUT if you open the serial monitor you will read the value in a "human" format)

Comment: But it's getting the error before the first loop, sorry, I'm really not sure what you mean..

Comment: ah, ok, then probably because /dev/ttyATH0 does not exist or is in use by some other program. that's fine.
i've undertand that you where having it while the program was running.
BTW how are you connecting Serial1 to your PC?

Comment: That should be this script doing it over wifi using UDP.

Comment: sorry but, what arduino/shield are you using? And exaclty what are you tryng to achieve? are tyou shure that this serial port exist?

Comment: I'm using an Arduino yun. I'm purely trying to get the data from the ATmega (arduino sketch) to be sent over UDP by the python script on the Atheros processor. I'm pretty sure that's the write serial port. Will check now!

Comment: Where people are discussing serial use, they seem to be talking about /dev/ttyATH0

Comment: Yes it is. also it is serial1. What error you get? Di you try to reboot the yun? Maybe the serial port is still in use by some zombie code

Comment: Yeah, no luck. It gives the error straight away, unless I upload a blank arduino sketch. Then it looks like it's happy sitting and waiting.

Comment: Whays the error? Btw in establishContact should be println not print